# Use html file as body of Zend mail\message

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-mail

Not sure what's the syntax of having html files rendered when added to Zend\Mail\Message?

Here's a piece of code I have:

```
$mail = new Mail\Message();
$html = file_get_contents('content.html');
$mail->setBody($html);
```

Is it sufficient to set it up like this or do I need to specify the type of content somehow?

Thanks.

Comment: you need the mime and the charshet

Comment: Consider using https://github.com/Soflomo/Mail

Comment: I thought mime is for multiple parts, no? I thought there would be easier ways to do since all I have is html...

Answer (score 1):

You can attach it as a Mime part.

Example from the [docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.mail.message.html):

```
use Zend\Mail\Message;
use Zend\Mime\Message as MimeMessage;
use Zend\Mime\Part as MimePart;


$html = new MimePart($htmlMarkup);
$html->type = "text/html";

$body = new MimeMessage();
$body->setParts(array($text, $html, $image));

$message = new Message();
$message->setBody($body);
```

Comment: Yea I saw this post as well, but I was thinking since I have html only, wouldn't it be redundant to have multiple parts?

Comment: Well its just creating one part if you just add the html as a mime part